# Converting mmyy into a useable date

Tags: vba, date, excel, excel-formula

My question is very similar to this problem, but for Excel: [how do I convert mmyy to last day of month in netezza](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22566950/how-do-i-convert-mmyy-to-last-day-of-month-in-netezza) or this one: [Create a date from Credit Card expire in MMYY format](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5262109/create-a-date-from-credit-card-expire-in-mmyy-format).

Essentially I have a column filled with dates that have been written as mmyy i.e.

> 0215
>   0215
>   0215
>   0315
>   0315

The column has been saved as the data type: "Special".

How do I convert this data into a useable format? I don't mind if we put it into *dd/mm/yyyy* and use the first or the last day of the month that's fine.  Is there an Excel function that I could use or is this something I would have to do in VBA and if so, how?

Comment: I understand that the cell is displaying *0215* but if you look in the formula bar, are you seeing *0215* or *215*? Do you want to change the values in the cells or create another column with date values? Do you want the first or last day of the month; pick one.

Comment: seeing 215, new column and first

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the 'dates' starting in A2, use this formula in an unused column to the right,

```
=DATE(20&RIGHT(A2, 2), LEFT(TEXT(A2, "0000"), 2), 1)
```

Fill down as necessary. You will have to format as a date or you will receive the raw date value like *42064*.

If you need the end-of-month, add *1* to the month and change the day to *0* like,

```
=DATE(20&RIGHT(A2, 2), LEFT(TEXT(A2, "0000"), 2)+1, 0)
```

Answer (score 4):

30 characters:

```
=1*REPLACE("1/"&A1,5,1,"/201")
```

Subject to the dates concerned the `20` may be redundant.

Comment: Bonus points for brevity but a dozen or so extra characters will guard against *215* vs *0215* e.g. `=1*REPLACE("1/"&TEXT(A1, "0000;@"),5,0,"/20")`. My m/d/yy regional system also interprets the OP's first sample value as 02-Jan-2015. A small change to `=1*REPLACE(TEXT(A1, "0000;@"),3,0,"/1/20")` addresses the regional issue.

Answer (score 2):

use this

```
=DATEVALUE("01/"&LEFT(A1;2)&"/20"&RIGHT(A1;2))
```

[image]

do not forget to change Format Cells to "Date" for column "B"